# A fair mapping of all values in the range [$0, 2^{32}$[ to each value in the range [$0, N$[

Tags: linear-transformations

I'm a programmer & lately working on improving the performance of a certain hashing algorithm. I was reading an article about reducing values of a range & i couldn't understand a certain mathematical notions.
So, basically, we have a range like [$0, 2^{32}$[ ($32$-bits integers) & i want to fairly map them to integers in the range [$0, N$[ where $N$ is a $32$-bits integer.
The most common & easy to understand way to achieve this goal is by using division remainder, that is to say, we take random value $x$ from the range [$0, 2^{32}$[ and get its mapping $n$ in the range [$0, N$[ using the formula $n = x \% N$
Now, because this calculation is not very efficient on processors, the article proposed a different scheme : $$n = \frac{x * N}{2^{32}}$$
The author, then, added an explanation which i didn't understand (mainly the part in bold):

> So how can I tell that the map is fair?
>
> By multiplying by $N$, we take integer values in the range [$0, 2^{32}$) and
>   map them to multiples of $N$ in [$0, N * 2^{32}$). **By dividing by $2^32$, we map
>   all multiples of N in [$0, 2^{32}$) to 0, all multiples of N in [$2^{32}, 2 *
> > 2^{32}$) to one, and so forth**. To check that this is fair, we just need to
>   count the number of multiples of N in intervals of length $2^{32}$. This
>   count must be either ceil($2^{32}/N$) or floor($2^{32}2/N$).

If someone could explain the paragraph in a simpler way but before, if he could explain what is a fair map ?

Comment: "Fair" means every value occurs the same number of times (as closely as possible). You might be able to understand the argument if you work out what happens to every starting value for $4$-bit integers and, say $N=5$. Then every value in the range should appear about $16/5$ times That's not a useful case for programming since there are just $16$ such integers, but you should see the pattern.